# ffmpeg for android, out of memory on decoding rotate mp4 file with openh264

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

### Version

- ffmpeg : 4.0.2
- openh264: 1.8.0

### Problem

I try to trim a `.mp4` file which `metadata` info contains rotate info, but I failed with the error information.

#### The file stream info :

```
  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-10-09T09:40:53.000000Z
    location        : +39.8983+116.4145/
    location-eng    : +39.8983+116.4145/
    com.android.version: 6.0
  Duration: 00:00:10.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8671 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 8563 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T09:40:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T09:40:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

#### ffmpeg cmd

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -threads 4 -b:v 2000k -vcodec libopenh264 -acodec copy -ss 0 -t 3 -f mp4 -movflags faststart -strict -2 ./output.mp4
```

#### result

```
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Out of memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Then I found this answer: [ffmpeg-for-android-out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867307/ffmpeg-for-android-out-of-memory-on-encoding-h264), after i added `-noautorotate` command to my cmd, the video is trimmed successful.

If I use `-vcodec copy` instead of `-vcodec libopenh264`, the result also is ok, I wonder if there is a bug when `libopenh264` decode with ffmpeg's autorotate function.

I wipe the video's rotate info from metadata with `-metadata:s:v:0` command, the newly video can be trimmed successful with the origin cmd :(

Comment: Show the complete log from the failing command.

Comment: [log.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Asa9lWjyknAkacx-VqSvbI41x8Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. Due to your usage of `--disable-filters` you need to manually enable the hflip/vflip filters:

```
--enable-filter=aresample,crop,hflip,scale,transpose,vflip
```

Some filters (such as the format filter) will be automatically enabled in this case.

Comment: @daque This log doesn't seem to be any different than before. You need to re-compile `ffmpeg` with the options I listed in the answer.

Comment: that works for me :) thank u. I re-compile ffmpeg with `hflip` and `vflip` filters, then the video can be trimmed successful without `--noautorotate`. I wonder why the `command` takes `40 seconds` to trim a `15 senconds` video, if my command was wrong?

Comment: @daque 1) Video encoding is processor intensive. 2) You're doing it on a phone with a slower processor than a typical desktop. 3) openh264 is probably not optimized as well as x264. 4) I am not knowledgeable about hardware encoding options you may have on Android but it would be worth investigating.